# How to comment in Javascript in an ASPX page so the comment is not rendered

Tags: javascript, asp.net

In the non-JavaScript code area `ctl+k+c` writes `<%--` etc and the contents within are **not** rendered.
But using `ctl+k+c` within the JavaScript area of ASPX page prefaces each line with `//` and the line **is** rendered.

Comment: Pretty sure it's not possible.

Comment: Have you tried using `<%--` within the JavaScript code? It should work. You don't have to be a slave to ctrl+k,c.

Comment: Yep <%-- works fine. JLRishe you're a genius and I'm a non-lateral thinker. But I'll work on it! Thanks.

Comment: try <%-- [comment here] --%>

Answer (score 0):

While ASP.NET compile ASPX page it removes all the ASPX page comment(<%--) but it can't removes the javascript comment. so that way you see in rendered page.